# Any way to automatically compress a .gif file?

Tags: image-processing, gif

I have a 2.0 mb gif I want to make smaller, preferably by dropping some frames.

Is there a command line utility or a program that will do it for me automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into the webm format: it's like a more optimized gif!

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1107200/optimize-animated-gif-size-in-command-line

Answer (score 10):

ImageOptim uses [Gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) for its Gif compression. As far as I know, it works quite well (I don't generally use Gif these days). From their site:

> Optimize your animations! This stores
>   only the changed portion of each
>   frame, and can radically shrink your
>   GIFs. You can also use transparency to
>   make them even smaller. Gifsicle’s
>   optimizer is pretty powerful, and
>   usually reduces animations to within a
>   couple bytes of the best commercial
>   optimizers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [the Gimp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gimp)[image: Install gimp] to remove some frames from the GIF as well as re-optimizing the file by saving it back to a GIF again.

Comment: How do you re-optimise the file on saving in Gimp?

Answer (score 4):

I use [ezgif.com/optimize](http://ezgif.com/optimize), as GIMP and other tools aren't good at this job. The difference is that ezgif uses a `gifsicle` modification (with a `lossy` flag), not available on the `apt` version. See release 1.82.1 [here](https://github.com/pornel/giflossy/releases) (replace `/usr/bin/gifsicle` with the appropriate one for your system (the binary ending with `-static`).

My notes on a full gif optimisation workflow are [here](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Gif-terminal-manipulation).

**Edit**: current script as kept in use will be updated on GitHub [here](https://github.com/lmmx/dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc/bashrc_functions_gif)

I won't describe how I do it all here, the general idea is a few bash functions/aliases:

```
function gifopt() {
    # args: $input_file ($loss_level)
    if [ -z "$2" ]
    then
        # use default of 30
        local loss_level=30
    elif [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ "$2" -ge 30 -a "$2" -le 200 ]
    then
        local loss_level=$2
    else
        echo "${2:-"Loss level parameter must be an integer from 30-200"}" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
    local inputgif="${1?'Missing input file parameter'}"
    local gifname="$(basename $inputgif .gif)"
    local basegifname=$(echo "$gifname" | sed 's/_reduced_x[0-9]//g')
    local outputgif="$basegifname-opt.gif"
    gifsicle -O3 --lossy="$loss_level" -o "$outputgif" "$inputgif";
    local oldfilesize=$(du -h $inputgif | cut -f1)
    local newfilesize=$(du -h $outputgif | cut -f1)
    echo "File reduced from $oldfilesize to $newfilesize as $outputgif"
}

function gifopt() {
    # args: $input_file ($loss_level)
    if [ -z "$2" ]
    then
        # use default of 30
        loss_level=30
    elif [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ "$2" -ge 30 -a "$2" -le 200 ]
    then
        loss_level=$2
    else
        echo "${2:-"Loss level parameter must be an integer from 30-200"}" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
    local inputgif="${1?'Missing input file parameter'}"
    local gifname="$(basename $inputgif .gif)"
    local basegifname=$(echo "$gifname" | sed 's/_reduced_x[0-9]//g')
    local outputgif="$basegifname-opt.gif"
    gifsicle -O3 --lossy="$loss_level" -o "$outputgif" "$inputgif";
    local oldfilesize=$(du -h $inputgif | cut -f1)
    local newfilesize=$(du -h $outputgif | cut -f1)
    echo "File reduced from $oldfilesize to $newfilesize as $outputgif"
}

function gifspeedchange() {
  # args: $gif_path $frame_delay (1 = 0.1s)
  local orig_gif="${1?'Missing GIF filename parameter'}"
  local frame_delay=${2?'Missing frame delay parameter'}
  gifsicle --batch --delay $frame_delay $orig_gif
  local newframerate=$(echo "$frame_delay*10" | bc)
  echo "new GIF frame rate: $newframerate ms"
}
```

The `--lossy` flag takes an integer from 30 to 200, so for best quality:

```
gifsicle -O3 --lossy=30 -o output.gif input.gif
```

With the above function `gifopt` you could simplify matters, since it defaults to 30

```
gifopt input.gif
```

...the output would be automatically named `input-opt.gif`. You could change the function to use the `--batch` flag for in-place editing but I wouldn't recommend overwriting your starting material.

That function also works to remove any `_reduced_x` suffix added by the frame count reduction function, i.e. you could have an intermediate file `input_reduced_x2.gif` (a step that would ~halve file size by dropping every other frame).

If you did do that the speed may change, fixed with `gifspeedchange input-opt.gif 5` for example, to use a 50ms frame delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your .gif file on Gimp easily.

Just Save as .gif and then compress or you can save in other extension as .jpeg or other.

Comment: How do you compress in Gimp?

Answer (score 0):

Trim some of the colour palette 512, 256, 128 etc....
See here:

Use gifsicle (available for Mac OS X, Windows, DOS, Debian, FreeBSD and NetBSD).

```
gifsicle -i anim.gif -O3 --colors 256 -o anim-opt.gif
```

some examples https://superuser.com/questions/1107200/optimize-animated-gif-size-in-command-line